# How can I improve this question so that it gets reopened?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

[Should classes with public non-virtual destructors be marked "final"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810700/should-classes-with-public-non-virtual-destructors-be-marked-final)

In what way is it different from this other good question that was not closed?
[In C++, should I almost always use virtual inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543537/in-c-should-i-almost-always-use-virtual-inheritance)

Comment: Design approrach X has some features.  Some will see feature Y as an advantage, some as a disadvantage, hence opinion-based, hence off-topic.

Comment: @Jon I don't think his question is a bad one. "final" makes a very non opinion-based change to the code. He could very well remove the "advantage/disadvantage" part and ask the same thing with "why should I mark classes..."; "what are the implications of..." - probably a duplicate but certainly not opinion-based.

Comment: Haven't read the question, but the title has me reaching for the close vote button already. "Advantages and disadvantages of X" is clearly *too broad*

Comment: The C++ question was asked 5 years ago, and guidelines evolve over time (and other [se] sites are created). Existence of a prior question isn't really relevant; what matters is whether the question fits the guidelines in effect *at the time the question is asked*.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? Someone is asking how to better adhere to our site's guidelines and expectations. Why discourage that?

Comment: I don't think this question is totally equivalent to "what is the advantage of...",at least I think the function of "final" is quite base on fact, it can be answered with less opinion by explaining the function or mechanism of "final"

Answer (score 4):

That post, in its current form, can be closed for the following reasons.

1. Too broad

   - Any answers to the question will be extremely long, your question should be able to be answered with a few paragraphs or less.
   - If your question could take up an entire chapter in a programming book, it is probably too broad for Stack Overflow.
2. Primarily Opinion Based

   - Questions that don't have a concrete answer are generally going to be based on opinions and not facts.
3. Unclear What You're Asking

   - It is unclear exactly what your question is asking, which adds to the Too Broad close reason.
4. No MCVE

   - Generally, questions on Stack Overflow should be about a specific programming problem, so you should include some code demonstrating the specific programming problem.
   - There are some exceptions to this rule but, as far as I can tell, your question is not one of those exceptions.

**I don't think that there is actually any way of salvaging that question without completely changing the question.** If you asked about a specific problem relating to the concept that you're asking about, possibly. But, if you're asking about the upsides and downsides of a certain method, it will probably be closed for the same reasons above.

In its current form, your question is off-topic for [programmers.stackexchange.com](//programmers.stackexchange.com), see [**Discuss this ${blog}**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6418/31260), [**What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260) and [**What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260). However, you may have an easier time editing it to be on-topic there. Keep in mind that their rules about what can or cannot be asked are more strict than Stack Overflow's rules. If that is what you end up doing, I want to stress that you **read the information available in their [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/asking) about how to ask questions, what topics can be discussed and what topics cannot.**

Also, if you have working code and you would like others to review it to suggest possible down-sides there is also [codereview.stackexchange.com](//codereview.stackexchange.com), **but their rules are just as strict as prog.se so make sure you read the relevant [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) information there as well *before posting your question***

**However, there might be no amount of editing that can make your question on-topic on any Stack Exchange site.** In which case, there is simply nothing you can do about it.

Comment: this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6418/31260) and [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: That's why I said "may be", and mentioned reading the help center information, but thanks for the relevant links.

Comment: consider [edit]ing to stress that as written, the question may have a bad luck over there

Comment: Edited. Does that work better?

Comment: I am not disagreeing what you say, just think the answer is still not explaining/deducing why this (specific) question is closed very clearly, it is just repeating the rules , it is better to explain which part/keyword is too broad/opinion based (e.g.:is "final" too complex to explain? is the usage of "final" opinion based? "There are some exceptions to this rule" then which is the exception case?...).

Comment: "*I don't think that there is actually any way of salvaging that question without completely changing the question. If you asked about a specific problem relating to the concept that you're asking about, possibly. But, if you're asking about the upsides and downsides of a certain method, it will probably be closed for the same reasons above.*" Pretty much the entire question is the problem, that's why I said I didn't think it could be salvaged through editing. @amuse.

Comment: In my opinion, you can bold that sentence or put it to the first paragraph.

Comment: I bolded the first sentence of that paragraph @amuse.